# invalid syntax when use device_count{'GPU': 1,2,3} in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

all,

I meet a SyntaxError when I try to let tensorflow only use specific GPU, here is the code and err info, does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks very much!

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldHFn.jpg)

[err info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvzua.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided states that you have a syntax error.

To manually run code on your GPU you can do the following:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):
  ##your code
```

And if your aim was to run code on multiple GPU's try this:

```
for d in ['/device:GPU:2', '/device:GPU:3']:
  with tf.device(d):
    ##your code
```

You can find more information here: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu